# angular micro front-end by module-federation

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, micro-frontend, angular-module-federation

I wanna create micro front-end applications
I have done it by module-federation and I followed this [page](https://blog.bitsrc.io/an-easy-to-follow-guide-to-create-angular-micro-frontends-9e6b7c0fff78) guid

but I have a problem, I want to every project has own style.

when ever i redirect url from dynamic app to remote app, style.scss from remote app does not load and deacuse of this reason my styles do not work.
can you help me how i can fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can employ the **proxy component strategy**.

1. Create a file named **proxy.component.ts** and set the encapsulation to **ViewEncapsulation.None**. `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`
2. Create a file named **proxy.component.scss** and import all the styles you need into it. Then, set it as the styleUrls inside the proxy component Ts file. `styleUrls: ['./proxy.component.scss'],`
3. Place all your **remote MFE** (Micro-Frontend) routes as children of the **ProxyComponent** in your the main router module using the following configuration:

   `RouterModule.forChild([`

   `{ path: '', component: ProxyComponent, children:`

   `[`

   `{ path: '', component: SampleComponent // or lazily load the module of any page } ] }`

   `])`